# R and Random Forest: How caret and pROC deal with positive and negative class?

Tags: r, r-caret, roc, confusion-matrix, proc-r-package

In the past days, I've been analyzing the performance of R's implementation of Random Forest and the different tools available in order to obtain:

- AUC
- Sensitivity
- Specificity

Thus, I've used two different methods:

- mroc and coords from **pROC** library in order to obtain the performance of the model at different cutoff points.
- confusionMatrix from **caret** library in order to obtain the optimal performance of the model (AUC, Accuracy, Sensitivity, Specificity, ...)

The point is that I've realized that there is some differences between both approaches.

I've developed the following code:

```
suppressMessages(library(randomForest))
suppressMessages(library(pROC))
suppressMessages(library(caret))

set.seed(100)

t_x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100),ncol=10))
t_y <- factor(sample(c("A","B"), 10, replace = T), levels=c("A","B"))

v_x  <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(50),ncol=10))
v_y <- factor(sample(c("A","B"), 5, replace = T), levels=c("A","B"))

model <- randomForest(t_x, t_y, ntree=1000, importance=T);
prob.out <- predict(model, v_x, type="prob")[,1];
prediction.out <- predict(model, v_x, type="response");

mroc <- roc(v_y,prob.out,plot=F)

results <- coords(mroc,seq(0, 1, by = 0.01),input=c("threshold"),ret=c("sensitivity","specificity","ppv","npv"))

accuracyData <- confusionMatrix(prediction.out,v_y)
```

If you compare the **results** and **accuracyData** variables, you can see that the relationship between sensitivity and specificity is the opposite.

That is, the confusionMatrix results are:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction A B
         A 1 1
         B 2 1

               Accuracy : 0.4             
                 95% CI : (0.0527, 0.8534)
    No Information Rate : 0.6             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.913           

                  Kappa : -0.1538         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.000           

            Sensitivity : 0.3333          
            Specificity : 0.5000          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.5000          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.3333          
             Prevalence : 0.6000          
         Detection Rate : 0.2000          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.4000          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.4167          

       'Positive' Class : A
```

But if I look for such Sensitivity and Specificity in the coords calculation, I find them swapped:

```
     sensitivity specificity       ppv       npv
0.32         0.5   0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
```

Apparently, Sensitivity and Specificity is are opposite in coords and confusionMatrix.

Taking into account that confusionMatrix identifies correctly the positive class, I assume that this good interpretation of Sensitivity and Specificity.

My question is: *Is there any way of forcing coords to interpret the positive and negative classes in the way I want to?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the output of `confusionMatrix`, you can see this:

```
       'Positive' Class : A
```

Now looking at `mroc`, class B is taken as the positive class:

```
Data: prob.out in 3 controls (v_y A) < 2 cases (v_y B).
```

Basically, `pROC` takes the levels of your factor as Negative, Positive and `caret` does the exact opposite. You can specify your levels explicitly with `pROC` to get the same behaviour:

```
mroc <- roc(v_y,prob.out,plot=F, levels = c("B", "A"))
```

Or depending on your preferred behaviour, with the `positive` argument of `confusionMatrix`:

```
accuracyData <- confusionMatrix(prediction.out,v_y, positive = "B")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you will get identical results using both the methods (it's all about positive and negative class factor levels):

```
accuracyData <- confusionMatrix(prediction.out,v_y, positive='A')
accuracyData



Confusion Matrix and Statistics

             Reference
    Prediction A B
             A 1 0
             B 2 2                         

             Accuracy : 0.6             
                 95% CI : (0.1466, 0.9473)
    No Information Rate : 0.6             
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.6826          

                  Kappa : 0.2857          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.4795          

            Sensitivity : 0.3333          
            Specificity : 1.0000          
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.5000          
             Prevalence : 0.6000          
         Detection Rate : 0.2000          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.2000          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.6667          

       'Positive' Class : A   


mroc <- roc(v_y,prob.out,plot=F, levels=c("B", "A"))
results <- coords(mroc, 0.49, "threshold", ret=c("specificity", "sensitivity", "accuracy",
                                      "tn", "tp", "fn", "fp", "npv", "ppv", "1-specificity",
                                      "1-sensitivity", "1-accuracy", "1-npv", "1-ppv"))
results 

specificity   sensitivity      accuracy            tn            tp            fn            fp           npv           ppv 1-specificity 
    1.0000000     0.3333333     0.6000000     2.0000000     1.0000000     2.0000000     0.0000000     0.5000000     1.0000000     0.0000000 
1-sensitivity    1-accuracy         1-npv         1-ppv 
    0.6666667     0.4000000     0.5000000     0.0000000
```